# What does joinOnce do in NEHotspotConfiguration do?

Tags: ios, iphone, networking

I am trying to do autoconnect in iOS with below code

```
if([Utils isEmpty:password]){
  configuration = [[NEHotspotConfiguration alloc] initWithSSID: wifiSSID];
}else{
  configuration = [[NEHotspotConfiguration alloc] initWithSSID: wifiSSID passphrase: password isWEP: NO];
}
configuration.joinOnce = YES;

/* Alert the OS that the user wants to connect to the WiFi */
[[NEHotspotConfigurationManager sharedManager] applyConfiguration: configuration completionHandler: ^ (NSError * _Nullable error) {
  if (nil == error) {
    DLog (@ "Is Connected!!");
    [WiFiManager sendCallback:CONNECTED callback:callback];
  } else {
    DLog (@ "Error is:%@", error);
    [WiFiManager sendCallback:UNKNOWN callback:callback];
}}];
```

Here I have joinOnce = YES.
What does this actually do when it is set to NO.
I don't find any real difference between YES and NO.

Anyone please explain.

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration/2887518-joinonce) seems pretty clear

Comment: Did that mean if joinOnce is set to false, the wifi will not be disconnected when app is killed or in background?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @Paulw11..Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

When `joinOnce` is set to `true`, it means that the connection to that hotspot will be disconnected and the configuration will be forgotten as soon as the device sleeps or your application has been in the background for some time.

Comment: Does `joinOnce` have a default value? What if I don't bother to set `joinOnce` at all?